# How can we pass junit Behave command line arguments in .ini file

Tags: python-behave

I am trying to replace --junit command line arguments in behave.ini file, other arguments like -D and format=plain are working fine. But --junit is not working for me, please find the command below,

```
behave --junit --junit-directory Reports/results

behave.ini/
[behave]
junit=True
junit-directory=Reports/results
```

Is there any way to resolve or is there any thing wrong ?

Thanks,
Ranjith

Comment: what's not working exactly? what do you expect, and what actually happens?

Comment: Look at the ``behave.configuration`` module implementation and search for "junit". The dest=... attribute contains the python attribute name that is also used in the config-file. Dashes are normally replace by underscores. Therefore:

```ini
# -- FILE: behave.ini
[behave]
junit=True
junit_directory=Reports/results
```
SEE ALSO: http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behave.html#configuration-parameters

Comment: Thank you jenisys...!!! Instead of junit-directory=Reports/results i just replaced junit_directory=Reports/results it's working fine.

Comment: @jenisys, seeing as this fixes the issue, you may consider posting this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `behave.configuration` module implementation and search for `junit`. The `dest=` attribute contains the python attribute name that is also used in the config-file. Dashes are normally replace by underscores. Therefore:

```
ini # -- FILE: behave.ini
[behave] 
junit=True 
junit_directory=Reports/results
```

[Reference](http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behave.html#configuration-parameters)

Answer originally provided by [jenisys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649302/jenisys) in comments.